# Transform UpperTriangular to Cholesky in Julia

Tags: julia

Having a dataset X, I am trying to perform a Cholesky factorization, followed by a Cholesky update. My setting is the following:

```
data = readtable("PCA_transformed_data_gt1000.csv",header= true)
data = delete!(data, :1)
n,d = size(data)

s = 6.6172
S0 = s*eye(d)
kappa_0 = 0.001
nu_0 = d
mu_0 = zeros(d)
S0 = LinAlg.chol(S0+kappa_0*dot(mu_0,mu_0'))
```

The type of S0 is

```
julia> typeof(S0)
UpperTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}
```

I am trying to perform the Cholesky update as

```
U = sqrt((1+1/kappa_0)) * LinAlg.lowrankdowndate!(S0, sqrt(kappa_0)*mu_0)
```

and get the following error

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching lowrankdowndate!(::UpperTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}, ::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  lowrankdowndate!(::Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{T,S<:AbstractArray{T,2}}, ::Union{Base.ReshapedArray{T,1,A<:DenseArray,MI<:Tuple{Vararg{Base.MultiplicativeInverses.SignedMultiplicativeInverse{Int64},N}}},DenseArray{T,1},SubArray{T,1,A<:Union{Base.ReshapedArray{T,N,A<:DenseArray,MI<:Tuple{Vararg{Base.MultiplicativeInverses.SignedMultiplicativeInverse{Int64},N}}},DenseArray},I<:Tuple{Vararg{Union{Base.AbstractCartesianIndex,Colon,Int64,Range{Int64}},N}},L}}) at linalg/cholesky.jl:502
```

I tried something like

```
convert(S0,Base.LinAlg.Cholesky)
```

but got the following

```
ERROR: MethodError: First argument to `convert` must be a Type, got [2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239 0.0; 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.57239]
```

Any ideas how to perform that task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two Cholesky factorization methods and it seems you need the other one, which returns a Cholesky variable. The other method is `cholfact`. From a Cholesky variable, you can extract an upper triangular factor by indexing with `:U` like so:

```
C = LinAlg.cholfact(M)
U = C[:U]  # <--- this is upper triangular
```

For the code in the question, this becomes:

```
data = readtable("PCA_transformed_data_gt1000.csv",header= true)
data = delete!(data, :1)
n,d = size(data)
s = 6.6172
S0 = s*eye(d)
kappa_0 = 0.001
nu_0 = d
mu_0 = zeros(d)
S1 = LinAlg.cholfact(S0+kappa_0*dot(mu_0,mu_0))

U = sqrt((1+1/kappa_0)) * LinAlg.lowrankdowndate!(S1, sqrt(kappa_0)*mu_0)[:U]
```

The changes are to the `dot` product (transpose is unnecessary and causes problem in 0.6), and indexing the result of the `lowrankdowndate!` with `[:U]` to get the upper triangular matrix. Also, `S1` is used for the result of `cholfact` instead of overwriting `S0` for type stability.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it helps a lot! Solves the issue, thank you! Another question is that if I try to do a similar thing as

`U = LinAlg.lowrankdowndate!(S1, x)[:U]`

I get the following error

`ERROR: Base.LinAlg.PosDefException(1)
 in lowrankdowndate!(::Base.LinAlg.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at ./linalg/cholesky.jl:519`

Comment: @LeonidasSouliotis `S1` is probably not positive semi-definite for some reason. Very often it is numerical inaccuracy, where some 0 eigenvalues becomes slightly negative. The solution is to add `λ*eye(S1)` for some small λ.